# send UI controls entered data values to C++ function

Tags: c++, sqlite

Anyone help me how to send UI controls entered data values to C++  function
like in C#,

### in C#:

SaveData(txtUsername.value,txtAge.value){
}

HOW WE CAN SEND DATA WHICH IS ENTERED FROM UI TO C++ FUNCTION

THANKING YOU,

Comment: What are you using in your UI?

Comment: You mean TextInput? Looks like it has a `text` member.

Answer (score 0):

If your calling SaveData and passing txtUsername.value and txtAge.value as the value in the ui text boxes like:

`SaveData(txtUsername.value,txtAge.value);`

You should be able to do something like this to store those values to predefined variables:

```
SaveData(string username, int age)
{
    usernameVar.setValue(username);
    ageVar.setValue(age);
}
```